# How to create standalone browserify bundle exporting directly to window?

Tags: browserify

I want to create a standalone browserify bundle which attaches the exported objects directly to the `window` object, not nested under a wrapper object attached to `window`.

Doing this, browserify ignores the window:

```
browserify main.js --standalone window > bundle.js
```

The `main.js` file looks like this:

```
var ModuleA = require('./module-a.js');
var ModuleB = require('./module-b.js');

module.exports = {
  ModuleA: ModuleA,
  ModuleB: ModuleB
}
```

I want both modules exposed directly in the global namespace: `window.ModuleA` and `window.ModuleB`.

The [documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) doesn't provide an obvious solution.

Can you help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
global.ModuleA = require('./module-a.js');
global.ModuleB = require('./module-b.js');
```

You could also use `window` instead of `global`.

Answer (score 9):

The argument for `--standalone` is supposed to be the name of the global variable that you want to assign to the module. In your example, you are using "window", which will probably cause some strange things to happen in your site.

Instead of forcing the modules into the global scope (some devs might not want them there due to conflicts), do something like this:

`browserify main.js --standalone TheModulesAB > bundle.js`

Then you will be able to load `bundle.js` and reference your modules like so:

```
TheModulesAB.A //module-a.js

TheModulesAB.B //module-b.js
```